# How do coaster table pagers order themselves?

Tags: network

You've probably seen them. Those coaster or puck size electronic things they give you at a restaurant to buzz you when your food is ready.

A seemingly common element of their design is that they have a pair (sometimes more) of metal posts that (apparently) run through the device. These facilitate the stacking of the devices in to a pile on a charger. I assume the current just runs up the common bus created by the posts as they are aligned to be on top of each other.

[image: Pager Tower]

Another feature of the pager is that they occasionally strobe an LED. Mostly I think just to let folks know the things are alive and charged.

However, when combined in to a stack (both on and off of the charger), the pagers will orient themselves so that when the pagers strobe individually, they will do so in order, say, from bottom to top. Giving the entire stack an attractive, animated light display.

So, my question, is how do the pagers self orient? Given that their only connectivity is through the pair of charging posts? Now, they may have an optical sensor to tell them they're underneath something. The may have a magnetic sensor to tell them they're near each other. But I'm still not sure how they coordinate to determine not just who's on top or bottom, but, indeed, their place in the stack.

What are some mechanisms that can facilitate this kind of connectivity and ordering?

Addenda responding to comments:

The animation behavior happens on and off the charger. It's very possible the LED blink could be a PING of some kind from the central server ("not only is the puck alive, but the server can sense it as well"). It's possible that the pucks can talk back to the server. How would the puck know the ID of the device is was placed upon to relay to the server (or was placed upon it). If the server is driving the ping, then it's transmitting the ping packets in order, with the animation mind. If you have several stacks of the pucks, you will have several animations (though I can't say if they happen simultaneously, this is all casual observation in a restaurant). It's very possible the devices might have other optical or proximity sensors, but seems excessive to do that just for this feature, which suggests they manifest it with the hardware they already have.

No, I'm not familiar with the 433Mhz protocol.

Comment: Fascinating solution to a fast food service notice. WHere did you find these?  Seems like a DC charger [port] for a Bluetooth communication product

Comment: Weight sensors would do :) But unlikely it is the actual way.

Comment: These are common in Southern California. Some places put identifiers underneath the tables and the pucks can pick that up and relay to the base station what table the puck is on as well.

Comment: Also could be that the order these are put onto the charger is logged somewhere.

Comment: They could use a serial form of communication on the DC pins too. ( AC coupled bus)  with some half-duplex protocol

Comment: *Given that their only connectivity is through the pair of charging posts* - I actually think these have some wireless connectivity, otherwise how will they "page" you? I'll expand on my previous comment - each time the pager is put onto or off the charger, it will send signal to a "server" - "ID such and such was just put/taken off the charger". The server will maintain the book-keeping of the order and synchronize the LEDs.

Comment: I made a PCB stack like this. As long as each PCB has two dedicated serial interfaces (not a bus), one to above and another to below they can count their order from the board at the end of the stack. A board can tell if it is at the end by pinging in both directions and waiting for a response. If there is none from a side, it knows it is on top, bottom, or alone. My PCB stack used B2B connectors, but there is nothing stopping you from using something like very weak IrDA or induction that only works at very close range.

Comment: That said, blinking pretty lights is pretty unimportant so it was probably a feature just throw in for free via code using communication hardware that already existed for a more important purpose (like detecting which table it is at). That would preclude something like IrDA which requires alignment instead favoring something that only requires close proximity like induction or RFID.

Comment: @Toor *blinking pretty lights is pretty unimportant* - You know, the main customer could just insist on it :)

Comment: @EugeneSh. Well if they are willing to spring for the cash to add on double-serial interfaces just for that, I am willing to oblige.

Comment: The answer was in my answer if you want to search for it.   If you have the time.  Dave deleted it. Meanwhile everyone is guessing

Comment: Dave dont be "that way". Of course it was not a simple answer but the info was all there and more with the entire *Theory of Operation* manual

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 No offence, but it was partially unformatted dump of mostly irrelevant info. We ban questions written this way, and I don't see why would we pass such an answers too. Personally I tried to find the relevant part and I could not.

Comment: neither could I, which is why I gave up formatting it... but then The wireless protocol is the unlying answer with some server client communication.

Comment: @WillHartung  Are you familiar with any Server-Client protocols for wireless 433MHz communication?

Comment: `their only connectivity is through the pair of charging posts` ..... are you certain? .... there may be optical ports on top and bottom of each device ...... i wonder if the vertical  animation would be interrupted if a sheet of  cardboard was  inserted between two of the devices

Comment: @jsotola Are you proposing an experiment? :) Actually the optical ports could be a simple ones which "see" the blinking LEDs themselves without any fancy dedicated IR/whatever (if the mechanical construction is allowing).

Comment: thinking about it now, the optical port idea makes no sense in terms of manufacturing cost  ..... the lights on the devices are most likely controlled by the charger wirelessly ..... the lights are turned on in the same order as being placed on the charger ..... no extra hardware would be required, only a  bit more software

Comment: @jstola The OP has stated that they behave this way even when taken off the charger. I imagine the system is robust enough that you could re-order it away from the charger without losing sequence (the original post kind of, but does not really make it clear if this is the case or not).

Comment: Why are people so eager to close under the premise of "Off-topic question about *use* of electronics". Where does this question ask how to use a product? Is that just some sort of catch-all? I see this all the time.

Comment: In terms of open-ended possibility speculation LEDs can also be used as light sensors, especially for something nearby with a known signal characteristic.  As for the user manual dump, if there is a conclusion in there, extracting it could make an answer on a site where the question could be on topic, but it is off topic here.

Answer (score -4):

Although this system may be offline from the internet the Server to Client communications must be shared over a 433 MHz channel using 4 digit address and data.

For IoT communication, these other forms were not used with the reasons given for IoT
https://www.getkisi.com/blog/internet-of-things-communication-protocols

In this case, the communication bandwidth is low but addressable.  Without knowing the intellectual property (IP) of this design, one can only guess how it is done. But most likely it is some form of *server* ( the listener to polls) to *client* ( the responder to polls) of communication.

> How do coaster table pagers order themselves?

- they respond to all inputs according to user interface and Server communication using the RF channel

> how do the pagers self orient?

- by the response to sequential polling from server and response on client LED display

> What are some mechanisms that can facilitate this kind of connectivity and ordering?

- Embedded "round-robin" Servo protocols and Wireless dedicated shared RF channels for Tx/Rx antenna.

Another example of a documented round-robin protocol which may be applied to a shared serial channel or a distribution channel or a shared wireless half-duplex channel

http://cdn.meccano.com/open-source/Meccano_SmartModuleProtocols_2015.pdf